# ngrx/store init store is not working properly

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

My store contains the following reducers :

```
export const centralStampState = {
  layoutState : layoutReducer, //this one is not initialized
  eventTabState : eventTabReducer,
  eventTimelineState: eventTimelineReducer,
  eventWorkflowState : eventWorkflowReducer,
  displayLayerState : displayLayerReducer,
  treeState : TreeReducer
}
```

The problem is that Angular initilize all the reducers , only one '`layoutState`' is initilized after firing the first action(Which cause an access to an `undefined` `Object`).

I am following the same implementation for all the reducers and states, and I didn't figure out the cause of this strange behavior.

The following is  the state of the Store after the initialization and after the first action
[image]

[image]

My implementation is the same for all the reducers.

```
export function layoutReducer(state: LayoutState = INITIAL_LAYOUT_STATE, action: Action) : LayoutState{
  switch (action.type){
    case UPDATE_SPLIT_CONFIG_DIMENSION :
      return updateSplitConfigDimension(state, action);
    case DISABLE_SPLIT_CONFIGURATION:
      return state;
    case UPDATE_SPLIT_AREA_VISIBILITY :
      return state;
    case RESTORE_DEFAULT_CONFIG_LAYOUT :
      return state;
  }
}

export function eventTabReducer(state: EventTabState = EVENT_TAB_INITIAL_STATE, action: CSAction): EventTabState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_SUPPORTED_REPORT_FIELDS:
          return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it, if it was JAVA instead of Typescript the code will not compile at all !!!!!!!!

I am missing the `default` statement inside the switch case, When Angular is dealing with the action `@ngrx/store/init` the `layoutReducer` will ignore this action and it seems that Angular will return `undefined` if it doesn't find the default statement.

```
export function layoutReducer(state: LayoutState = INITIAL_LAYOUT_STATE, action: Action) : LayoutState{
  switch (action.type){
    case UPDATE_SPLIT_CONFIG_DIMENSION :
      return updateSplitConfigDimension(state, action);
    case DISABLE_SPLIT_CONFIGURATION:
      return state;
    case UPDATE_SPLIT_AREA_VISIBILITY :
      return state;
    case RESTORE_DEFAULT_CONFIG_LAYOUT :
      return state;
    default:
      return state;// with this Angular can perform the ngrx init action
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow you saved my life. I spent a week trying to figure out what was wrong. Missed my deadline. Words cannot describe.

Comment: Thank you. At one point, somebody added and `if` around a return in our reducer without an else. Weird thing is that it only showed up as problem when we upgraded to ngrx 6.1 .